how can I transform the categorical data entered by the user using Target Encoding?
When fitting the model in google collab there doesnt seem to be any problem. However, when I try to create an interface using streamlit and pickle, Target encoder doesnt work and I am unable to solve it.
The error can be related to the dimension or it can be an error like this too:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split,GridSearchCV
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler,OneHotEncoder
from category_encoders import TargetEncoder
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
from sklearn.metrics import *
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
import pickle
import streamlit as st

with open("C:/Users/isma_/Desktop/VS Code/Violencia genero/model_violencia_genero.pkl","rb") as file:
   model= pickle.load(file)

with open("C:/Users/isma_/Desktop/VS Code/Violencia genero/oh_encoder.pkl","rb") as file:
   oh_encoder=pickle.load(file)

with open("C:/Users/isma_/Desktop/VS Code/Violencia genero/scaler_X.pkl","rb") as file:
   scaler_X=pickle.load(file)

with open("C:/Users/isma_/Desktop/VS Code/Violencia genero/target_encoder.pkl","rb") as file:
   target_encoder=pickle.load(file)

df=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/isma_/Downloads/archive (15)/Domestic violence.csv")
##########################
st.title("Violencia de género")
st.write(df.columns)
edad=st.sidebar.slider("Edad",1.0,120.0,df['Age'].mean(),1.0)
educacion=st.sidebar.select_slider("Educación",["Ninguna","Primaria","Secundaria","Terciaria"])
empleo=st.sidebar.selectbox("Empleo",["Desempleada","Semi-Empleada","Empleada"])
ingresos=st.sidebar.slider("Ingresos",0.0,float(df["Income"].max()),df["Income"].mean())
estado_civil=st.sidebar.selectbox("Empleo",["Soltera","Casada"])

data={
   'Age':edad,
   'Education ':educacion,
   'Employment ':empleo,
   'Income':ingresos,
   'Marital status ':estado_civil,
}
features=pd.DataFrame(data,index=[0])
st.write("Datos introducidos")
st.write(features)

#Label encoder
df['Violence ']=df['Violence '].map({"no":0,"yes":1})



#THIS IS WHAT I AM UNABLE TO DO
#I HAVE TRIED MANY THINGS
#Target encoder
X_selected = features[['Employment ']]
a=target_encoder.transform(X_selected, df['Violence '])
st.write(a)

